# Elvis operator with Run in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Im having a bit of trouble with this situation

```
a?.let {
    b?.let { }
}?: run { }
```

The thing is, if "b" is null, the run block is executed, even though the elvis operator is referencing the "a" let.
I already tried to use "apply" instead of "run", same thing happens

Comment: we need to see what happens in the `let`, because it all depends on that. Also, if `a` is null the `run block` will always execute and completely disregard `b`. Btw, if `a` is not null, and `b` is null, then the `let` will always return a null, thus executing the `run block`.

Comment: thats what i thought but:
https://i.imgur.com/tpC0abK.png

Comment: so how to prevent the b from calling the run block? will i have to use 'if else'?

Comment: you said that is what you thought, but look at my last sentence: `if a is not null, and b is null, then the let will always return a null, thus executing the run block`. It describes your run, a is not null and b is null, thus executing the run.

Comment: Yes, this is normal.  The solution is, in fact, to stop trying to use `?.let` magic and write more straightforward code with if and else.

Comment: i said "thats what i thought" before your edit, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that the `let` function returns whatever its last expression is. If the last expression evaluates to null (as `b?.let` would if `b` is null or the last line of that inner `let` evaluates to null), then the second part of the Elvis operator will be evaluated.

The solution is to never follow up a scope function call with an Elvis operator. It would work OK with `also` instead of `let` since it doesn't return the lambda result, but it's still obtuse-looking code that's hard to read. It's such an ugly pattern to use that [people make memes](https://www.reddit.com/r/mAndroidDev/comments/nvrx2d/nullsafe/h14vhf8?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) about how ridiculous it is.

For this particular case, I would refactor your code as follows.

```
val a = a
if (a != null) {
    b?.let {
        //...
    }
} else {
    //...
}
```